# Angular Bootstrap Tabs - Cannot control from child component

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-template, ng2-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am using Tabs from ng2-bootstrap, which I have put in my AppComponent. I am trying to switch active tabs in AppComponent from a button in the Child component. I see that the setTab method is being executed when the button is clicked and the tabs array is being modified. But the tabs don't switch. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  public tabs: any[] = [
    {title: 'Accounts', content: '', active: true},
    {title: 'Names', content: '', active: false}
  ];

  setTab(index: number): void {
    this.tabs[index].active = true;
    if (index==1) {
      this.tabs[0].active = false;
    } else {
      this.tabs[1].active = false;
    }
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<tabset>
  <tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index"
            [heading]="tab.title"
            [active]="tab.active"  
            (select)="setTab(i)">
    <div *ngIf="i==0">
      Accounts Content
      <app-accounts></app-accounts>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="i==1">
      Names Content
    </div>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

**accounts.component.html**

```
<div>
  <button (click)="setTab(1)">Click Tab2</button>
</div>
```

Don't have any code in AccountsComponent.

I just installed "bootstrap": "^3.3.7", "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.6.3" on top of default packages which were installed by cli. Followed instructions in https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/bootstrap4.md. Also, if I move the button to the AppComponent from the child component, I dont have any problem in controlling the tabs, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I solved this by putting an event emitter on the child component and a listener on the parent. Then you can set the tab by emitting the tab index as needed.